# Sttp, Circe, Json - how to deserialize Json to custom object?

Tags: json, scala, circe, sttp

I have a simple case class which models Http response:

```
case class Other(name: String, age: Int)
case class MyResponse(id: String, name: String, others: List[Other])
```

I created decoders for them:

```
implicit val decoderOther: Decoder[Other] = deriveDecoder[Other]
implicit val decoderMyResponse: Decoder[MyResponse] = deriveDecoder[MyResponse]
```

But when I call it on `sttp` http client:

```
basicRequest.(...).get(...).response(asJson[MyResponse].getRight).send(backend).map(_)
```

I got a `Desarialization` error:

```
sttp.client3.DeserializationException: DecodingFailure at .id Missing required field
```

I don't know why it cannot be parsed correctly. Decoders seems fine. When I change `MyResponse` to `circe` Json class it works fine:

```
Response([{ "id": "121", "name": "test", "others": [] }])
```

but I would like to parse it to my model. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

If you write `asJson[MyResponse]` you need `Encoder` rather than `Decoder`.

So add

```
implicit val encoderOther: Encoder[Other]           = deriveEncoder[Other]
implicit val encoderMyResponse: Encoder[MyResponse] = deriveEncoder[MyResponse]
```

You can replace `Encoder` and `Decoder` with `Codec`

```
implicit val codecOther: Codec[Other]           = deriveCodec[Other]
implicit val codecMyResponse: Codec[MyResponse] = deriveCodec[MyResponse]
```

```
MyResponse("121", "test", List()).asJson.noSpaces
// {"id":"121","name":"test","others":[]}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/W3wgn0gbRXyA1vRI6OyoUg/1